# Find the limit of the PDE

Tags: reference-request, limits, partial-differential-equations

Consider two following PDEs on functions $\psi_{1,2}(x,\lambda)$, $x \in \mathbb R^n$ depending on parameter $\lambda \in \mathbb C^n$:
$$
   \Delta_x \psi_1(x,\lambda) + 2i\lambda \cdot \nabla_x\psi_1(x,\lambda)=u(x), \quad (1)\\
   \Delta_x \psi_2(x,\lambda)+2i\lambda \cdot \nabla_x\psi_2(x,\lambda)=\lambda \cdot v(x), \quad(2)
$$
where $u(x) \colon \mathbb R^n \to\mathbb R$, $v(x) \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ are smooth rapidly decaying functions and $\psi_{1,2}(\infty,\lambda) = 0$ (for convenience). My question is if it is possible to say that there exist limits
$$
   \psi_1^\infty(x)=\lim\limits_{\lambda \to \infty} \psi_1(x,\lambda), \\
   \psi_2^\infty(x) = \lim\limits_{\lambda \to \infty} \psi_2(x,\lambda),
$$
and if they exist is it possible to say that they will satisfy some PDEs so that we can call the convinient PDEs limits of PDEs (1) and (2)? If it is possible, tell me please, which area of mathematics studies such questions and where can I find some information on it?